# Using the determinant to solve a system of equations

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, determinant

Here is the question: Factorise the determinant

$$\text{det}\begin{pmatrix}
z & 1 & 2 \\ 
1 & z & 3 \\ 
1 & 1 & z+1
\end{pmatrix}$$

and hence solve the system of equations

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
zx+y=2\\ 
x+zy=3\\ 
x+y=z+1
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I've factored the determinant to $(z-1)(z^2+2z-4)$, but I fail to see how to use the determinant to solve this system.

How can the determinant actually be used for this? After doing some research into potential methods, I came across something called Cramer's Rule (although I do not believe that this would be the intended method). Not to mention, it seems to only be useable for linear/planar equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system of linear equations can be written as 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
z&1&2\\
1&z&3\\
1&1&z+1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{bmatrix}\tag1
$$
If the matrix on the left is invertible there is no solution, so the only possibility is that $z$ is such that the determinant vanishes.  Once you know the possible values of $z$, you can substitute them in $(1)$ to get ordinary systems of linear equations with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind, I would like to offer a solution without using determinants. If we add the first two equations,
$$x+y+zx+xy=5 \implies (x+y)(z+1)=5$$
From the third equation, $x+y=z+1$
$$\therefore (z+1)^2=5 \implies z=-1\pm\sqrt5 \implies x+y=-1\pm\sqrt5$$
You can solve for $x$ and $y$ using the above.
Hope this helps.